# Binaural Dummy Head [DIY]

Tags: binaural, diy

I want to build myself a dummy head. I found a tutorial: http://digdagga.com/dummy/ using these silicone ears: http://www.binauralears.com/.

Has anyone tried it? Or has other easier/cheaper options? I want to use the DPA 4060 matched pair to do this, and they are expensive so I don't won't it to be destructive. I really want to be able to insert and take out the mics easily so I can use them in other scenarios too.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll get better results with other capsules. I've made checks with the 4060's and not worth for the money. I think you'll get the best results with the Sonic Studios (similar price i think). If you want cheaper options with good image try with Shure WL183 or Sound Professionals.

Also depends on what you want to get, stereo image, good definition, portability... My personal opinion is that is better to have a amazing stereo image than a high-end quality and definition.

Best regards.

Fran

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation about the 4060s. I mainly want to use them for location recording as lavs, and secondly I want them for my SFX recording kit. I feel like they will be the best as a combination of all elements. Might be wring though, busy researching a bunch on it! Any more inout would be appreciated. Also, I combined both your answers and deleted one :-) Just to keep it clean. 

Comment: @Fran what was wrong with 4060's? I was thinking about putting them inside a dummy head... My friend uses Earthworks QTC50 with his dummy head and it sounds amazing :-) but those mics are BIG

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully Colin Hart can chime in on this.  He has a post on his blog from last year recording a train with a DIY dummy head.  http://www.colinhartonline.com/?p=285

He might have some good dos and don'ts based on his experience.

Colin?